# Svelte : get ( 404 ─ 0.27ms ─ /flutter_service_worker.js?v=3796772977) after npm run dev and open site in Microsoft edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, svelte

I'm very new in svelte.
when I download new template using the following:

```
npx degit sveltejs/template svelte-app
cd svelte-app
npm install
npm run dev
```

the app is running as expected and I can see the site but I'm getting the following error:

```
  - Local:      http://localhost:8080
  - Network:    Add `--host` to expose

────────────────── LOGS ──────────────────

  [**:47:57] 200 ─ 8.27ms ─ /
  [**:47:57] 200 ─ 2.59ms ─ /global.css
  [**:47:57] 200 ─ 6.69ms ─ /build/bundle.css
  [**:47:58] 200 ─ 1.69ms ─ /build/bundle.js
  [**:47:59] 404 ─ 0.24ms ─ /flutter_service_worker.js?v=3796772977
  [**:48:29] 404 ─ 0.41ms ─ /flutter_service_worker.js?v=3796772977
```

is this because I used flutter?
note that will only happen in microsoft edge. I check it with chrome and opera, I will not get 404 errror

Comment: I created a simple demo and it works fine(not including `flutter_service_worker.js`).If possible, could you provide more details, how did you add this js resource to the project?

Comment: I did not add the `flutter_service_worker.js`. but  I make many "get start demo" like flutter, react, asp.net ... most of them use the local host ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by deleting cookies:
settings -> Cookies and data stored -> All cookies and site data

then search for localhost and delete the cookies